# Phonegap has speech to text api?

Tags: cordova

I am currently thinking about writing a Speech to Text app and I want to use PhoneGap to target multiple platforms.

However, is there any api that will allow me to do this with Phonegap? If not, is it in the roadmap and when?

Comment: There are other avenues of approach with an app such as this. I know goodle voice. Unofficial api for chrome http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/

Comment: Somebody has a lib written in ruby for it to examine https://github.com/taf2/speech2text. I've been playing around with it for a bit and am awaiting an official release.

Comment: In addition keep checking in the phonegap plugins. Depending on the platform it may not be to terribly difficult to implement this yourself in a plugin.  https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins

Comment: Is there a javascript implementation for the chrome api?

Comment: No there isn't but there are a couple of parts to take some note of that can be applied elsewhere in particular the request to the server and how he parses it into json here https://github.com/taf2/speech2text/blob/master/lib/speech/audio_to_text.rb

Comment: I know its ruby but conceptually that part wouldn't be to bad to implement. The other key thing would be to take note at how the audio is converted into bits and either find something similar or role your own. I was working on doing a rewrite of this in C# a while back so thats where I remembered it.

Comment: Another route, depending on your mobile device target(s) of choice would be to write a plugin. In particular android might be a relatively painless platform, considering how integrated its speech to text functionality is

Comment: Have you explored this any further? It would be very interesting to hear what you decided on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, is there any api that will allow me to do this with Phonegap?

The [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/) says no.

> If not, is it in the roadmap and when?

The [roadmap document](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/28291160/roadmap-planning) says no.

Comment: Thanks. there goes that plan. :)

Comment: @JD: There it goes indeed. :)

Answer (score 2):

I found a phonegap plugin at github - [link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SpeechRecognizer)
It should work i'm testing it myself...